# Why am i getting infinity loop?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to resize the container and set for it width and height. It is not all the part of code, but infinity loop appears then i call 
**$.fn.imageScale.resizeContainer** function, I can't find why?

```
$( window ).load(function(){    
    $( '#scalable_images' ).imageScale();
});

(function($){
$.fn.imageScale = function(){

    thisCallback = $( this ); // for usage in inner other function
    images = $( this ).find( 'img' ); // images
    imagesHolder = $( this ).find( '.item' ); // image holder
    frameSize = 34; // frame size
    sizingCof = 1.5; // image size cofficient to scale, 1.5 = 150% normal state
    speed = 600; // speed in ms

    $.fn.imageScale.resizeContainer();
    $.fn.imageScale.resize();
    OldContainerW = imagesHolder.width();
    OldOffsetL = offsetL;

    $( window ).bind( 'resize', function(){
        $.fn.imageScale.resizeContainer();
        $.fn.imageScale.resize();
        OldContainerW = imagesHolder.width();
        OldOffsetL = offsetL;
    });
}

$.fn.imageScale.resizeContainer = function(){

    var windowW = $( window ).width();
    var windowH = $( window ).height();
    var scaleImgH = windowH - frameSize * 2;
    var scaleImgW = windowW - frameSize * 2;

    $( this ).height( scaleImgH );
    $( this ).width( scaleImgW );
}
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you bind the resizeContainer function to the resize event, and in the resizeContainer function you resize the container, triggering the resize event again, which executes resizeContainer again, ad infinitum

Answer (score 1):

if you already create a function to trigger the resize event then why you are binding  it inside  the function

IF calling $( '#scalable_images' ).imageScale(); means resizing then replace the following code by the code below it

```
 $( window ).bind( 'resize', function(){

        $.fn.imageScale.resizeContainer();
        $.fn.imageScale.resize();
            OldContainerW = imagesHolder.width();
        OldOffsetL = offsetL;
    });
```

And Replace it by

```
  $.fn.imageScale.resizeContainer();
    OldContainerW = imagesHolder.width();
    OldOffsetL = offsetL;
```

Comment: I done something similar to your suggestion, but before your answer ;)